# Understanding the PDF DOM

Tags: vb.net, pdf, vba

I am writing an application that has to read and interpret data stored in some PDF files. The reading part is done but I am only able to get a dump of all the **words** on a page and not the format of the words. What I mean is that if I have to extract a table, I am getting the numbers in the table but not the markup which defines the table.

Further, there is some formatting used which displays a few of these numbers within parentheses (meaning that those numbers are negative) but the parentheses themselves are not part of the text. Hence, I am not able to distinguish between positive and negative numbers present in the PDF table!

How do you get the PDF markup along with the text? Is a PDF similar in structure to an XML with tags used to markup tables etc.? If not, then, is there a resource which describes the salient features of the PDF DOM?

I am using VBA and the Acrobat library (AcroExch etc.)

Comment: PDF doesn't really have a DOM. it's quite literally a PROGRAM, written in PostScript. As such, most of the formatting stuff is done via function calls that change states in the PDF interpreter.

Comment: I've removed the tags XML, HTML, and DOM since they have no relevance to the question.

Comment: @Marc B: Umm, no... PDF is **NOT** *'quite literally a PROGRAM'*. And it is **NOT** '*written in PostScript*' either. (Ghostscript's PDF *interpreter* is in big parts written in PostScript... but that's a different thing from 'PDF' itself altogether).

Comment: What pipitas said.  PDF is a binary file format.  It is entirely declarative.  No loops, no conditions, no variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "PDF markup" in the sense of HTML etc. A table in PDF cannot be distinguished from line art, other than by using OCR, which can be error-prone if the layout is complex. It is simply drawn using geometrical shapes, like in a vector-based graphics program.

Comment: But there is a visible structure! And the text is clearly separate from its structure. I just want to know where / in what form are instructions to represent certain text in a certain way stored and how to access them.

Comment: "Text" in PDF very often are single characters placed individually and precisely on the page, one after the other by the `Tj` operator, after the `Td` and `Tm` operators have "positioned" it. And most fonts used **are** bold or italic faces, selected+sized by the `Tf` operator.

Comment: This is **not** _entirely_ true. PDF file content can be "tagged" (starting with version 1.4) to provide information about a document's structure. While PDF tagging is optional and not present in all PDF documents, it can provide you with additional information than simply interpreting the page stream. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Standard/WS4A3903C4-FD2A-4ca4-A3C3-3FFEB1C7AD3B.html

Answer (score 4):

*"Is a PDF similar in structure to an XML with tags used to markup tables etc.?"*

***No, not at all.***

And there is no such thing as a 'DOM' either. Google for a file named *PDF32000_2008.pdf*. The current PDF specification for v1.7 (ISO spec) is that file. You should be able to locate it on the Adobe website.

Comment: Do you know which functions (in the Javascript for Adobe reference) can I use to access the formats which have been applied to any block of text?

Comment: You already found out about the Javascript for PDF reference? Then all info you're looking for is in there. Don't ask to spoonfeed it to you...

Comment: Hmm.. Have you ever read that reference? I read about all the methods available through the doc object (which is the JSO in ICA terminology) and none of the methods available can detect formatting applied to words - this means I cannot differentiate between numbers within parentheses and those without. Hence, my code cannot differentiate between positive and negative numbers. Hence my question, does anybody know of any such methods in the JS reference? I really do not think there is any spoonfeeding involved if you can answer that question correctly.

Comment: I dont think what you want is possible. PDF isnt a spreadsheet. PDF was designed as a way to display stuff on screen and on paper and to make both appearances match each other as closely as possible. (In PDF-1.0 you could not even search for strings -- you can do it nowadays which is an add-on afterwards...). Your original questions sounded more like asking to be spoonfed. If I misunderstood, I apologize. When you asked to access "formats to blocks of text" I took it you want to know if a font used is s.th. like *"italic, bold, 24pt, Helvetica"*, not if it is a positive or a negative number...

Answer (score 2):

As omz stated, text inside PDF does not really have a structure. You can take a look on the specification [here](http://PDF%20Reference,%20Sixth%20Edition,%20version%201.7). However, for some very specific files, there is something called PDF Tags, or PDF Marked Content, which is fairly new, and it aims to give PDF documents some kind of structure. If you target this kind of files specifically, you might be able to achieve something. Take a look on chapter 10 (Document Interchange) of the Adobe's specification for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you want to achieve can be done with less effort and faster by using **TET**, the Text Extraction Toolkit made by the fine folks from pdflib.com ( http://www.pdflib.com/products/tet/ ) ??

AFAIR, the TET has some (limited) support for table detection as well....

Comment: Is there a free / trial / free-for-non-commercial-use version of TET available?